# Advanced Rails ActiveRecord query using scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, rails-activerecord

I've been trying for a while to find the best way of querying for the desired result, but I always end up failing at some poing in the query.

Simplified database structure:

User:

```
id (integer)  
first_name (string)  
last_name (string)
```

CourseType:

```
title (string)
slug (string)
```

Course:

```
belongs_to :user  
belongs_to :course_type  
week (integer)  
sold (float)
```

My controller is calling a scope:

```
@users = User.sales_results(week)
```

And here's the scope in my model:

```
scope :sales_results, lambda { |week|
  joins(:courses => [:course_type])
  .select("
    users.id, users.first_name, users.last_name,
    SUM(courses.sold) as total_sold,
    COUNT(courses) as num_classes
  ")
  .where("courses.week = ?", week)
  .group('users.id')
}
```

This works fine, and I can use it in my template to show the total amount sold. Although I also want to show a second column where the value sold for some specific types of courses are summed up in. Something like this:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.total_sold %>
  <%= user.total_sold.where("course_types.slug IN ('H', 'S')") # not possible, but similar to what I desire %>
<% end %>
```

**Update**

I ended up adding another scope

```
  scope :sales_results_for_types, lambda { |week, types|
     sales_results(week).except(:group).where("course_types.slug IN (?)", types)
    .group('users.id')
  }
```

Then calling both scopes in my controller

```
@users = User.sales_results(...)
@users_filtered = User.sales_results_for_types(...)
```

Lastly iterating both results at the same time

```
<% @users.zip(@users_filtered).each do |user, filtered| %>
<%= filtered.total_sold %>
<%= user.total_sold %>
```

Until I figure out something better. Thanks guys for leading me on the right track.

Comment: I think you may have to define a scope just for in ['H', 'S'] and make another query to the database.  You might be able to get the data in one complicated SQL, but *that* might involve joining the tables a second time, and that's a much more elaborate join condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with having another query, you can use this

`user.joins(courses: :course_type).sum(:sold, group: 'course_types.slug')`

which will give you a hash where the keys are the slugs, and the values are the sums.